# scraping data from website using vba - problem

Tags: vba, ms-access, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the address, facility type and some other data from every facility on this search. I'm able to get the search results and the list of facilities but I cannot figure out how to get the data from the page.

EDIT
i've applied the suggestiong in the answer, here's the new code and the OBJECT REQUIRED error is at the DEBUG line
I'm trying to click on each link and get the name, address, facility type and whatever other data is on that page

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ie2 As New InternetExplorer
    'Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

    With ie2
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/fsSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        FacType = "Long-Term Care (Nursing Homes)"
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_0").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With
            
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            

        Pause (2)
        
        Dim list2 As Object, i2  As Long, line1 As String, line2 As String

        Set list2 = .Document.querySelectorAll("[href*='fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=']")
        
        For i2 = 0 To list2.Length - 1
            list2.Item(i2).Click
            Debug.Print .Document.querySelector(".infotable tr:nth-of-type(3) td + td").innerText
            
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Pause (2)

            address = Replace(Replace(Replace(line1 & " " & line2, "<span id=" & Chr(34) & "middleContent_lbAddress" & Chr(34) & ">", ""), "<br>", ", "), "</span>", "")

            WriteTable .Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3), .Document.getElementById("middleContent_Menu1").innerText

            .Navigate2 .Document.URL
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set list2 = .Document.querySelectorAll("[href*='fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=']")

        Next
        .Quit                                    '
    End With

End Sub
```

I get the OBJECT REQUIRED error at this line

**Address = Replace(Replace(Replace(.Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbAddress").outerHTML, "<span id=" & Chr(34) & "middleContent_lbAddress" & Chr(34) & ">", ""), "
", ", "), "", "")**

but I'm pretty sure that I'm using the wrong way to get the data anyway. So, even without the error I wouldn't have given me what I need.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ie2 As New InternetExplorer
    'Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

    With ie2
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/fsSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_0").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With
            
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            
        Dim list2 As Object, i2  As Long
        Set list2 = .Document.querySelectorAll("#main_table")
             
        For i2 = 0 To list2.Length - 1
            list2.Item(i2).Click

            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Pause (2)
    
            If .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbResultTitle") Is Nothing Then
                Pause (5)
            End If

            If .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbResultTitle").outerHTML Like "*Long-Term Care Facility*" Then
                FacType = "Long-Term Care (Nursing Homes)"
            End If

            Address = Replace(Replace(Replace(.Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbAddress").outerHTML, "<span id=" & Chr(34) & "middleContent_lbAddress" & Chr(34) & ">", ""), "<br>", ", "), "</span>", "")

            WriteTable .Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3), .Document.getElementById("middleContent_Menu1").innerText


            .Navigate2 .Document.URL
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set list2 = .Document.querySelectorAll("#main_table")

        Next
        .Quit                                    '
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try using xhr to fetch the content instead of IE?

Comment: hey, if it's not already obvious, i'm totally clueless and just copying and pasting code :) i was only able to find IE version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a single node `Set list2 = .Document.querySelectorAll("#main_table")`. Instead, assuming same structure for all results use something like:

```
Dim i As Long, line1 As String, line2 As String, address As String

Set list2 = .Document.querySelectorAll("[href*='fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=']")

For i = 0 To list2.Length - 1
    line1 = list2.Item(i).NextSibling.NextSibling.NodeValue
    line2 = list2.Item(i).NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.NodeValue
    address = line1 & " " & line2 'apply string cleaning here
Next
```

This targets initially the hyperlinks for each result, then moves across the br elements with nextSibling to get the address line 1 and 2. You will need to write some string cleaning on the address variable.

If you decide to click each hyperlink, then on the detailed info page use `.document.querySelector(".infotable tr:nth-of-type(3) td + td").innerText` to retrieve the full address.

An example of navigating to each page (check urls retrieved are complete and don't require a prefix)

```
Dim i As Long, address As String, urls(), numLinks As Long

Set list2 = .Document.querySelectorAll("[href*='fsFacilityDetails.aspx?item=']")
numLinks = List.Length - 1
ReDim urls(0 To numLinks)

For i = 0 To numLinks
    urls(i) = list2.Item(i).href
Next

For i = 0 To numLinks
    .navigate2 urls(i)
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    'time loop maybe goes here
    address = .Document.querySelector(".infotable tr:nth-of-type(3) td + td").innerText
    Debug.Print address
Next
```

Comment: You probably want to set address lines to variables, between On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0,  then test if not nothing before accessing nodeValue in case there are html differences across pages.

Comment: hey, i rememeber you))) can't get it to work, object required. i will post the code i'm now using in the original. and yes, i want to click each link because i need other things besides the address from each detail page

Comment: on which line did you get the error? And did you try ie.navigate2 list2.Item(0).href to see if you get to next page? You will need to extract all the href from list2 into an array and loop that array to navigate to each url as list2 will become invalid when you go to next page.

Comment: One sec, will try. Thank you! And this line errors Debug.Print .Document.querySelector(".infotable tr:nth-of-type(3) td + td").innerText

Comment: you need to be on the new page for that line. I.e. you need to first extract each href and navigate to it, then make sure you wait for page to load then use the line. You may need a timed loop for element to be present.

Comment: i can't even test now, it's asking for some login credentials, either the site is down or i ran it too many times

Comment: I have added an example above

Comment: thank you!!! where can i learn this? what is all this stuff called? and most importantly, how do you know what to look for on the website to know which method to use.

Comment: Look at the links in my profile. They are all useful ones. Not sure if I link to the Wise Owl Web-Scraping YouTube tutorials but they are good. For your last question - it is about learning HTML and how to interact with a webpage in VBA. There are now also lots of examples on SO. I would lean more towards the querySelector answers as they are generally more flexible and quicker.

Comment: Oh I remember wiseowl. You gave then to me before and I watched them but got sidetracked. So much stuff to do at work... but I need to figure this out finally.

Comment: Sure and you can always stop by the [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus-) to discuss things and bounce ideas.

Comment: sorry, one more question, how do i get the county? is it by tab TR? but at what point? it's on the search page, not the detail page

Comment: .header on the first page. You should open a new question as you will need a little more complex code to ensure you pair the right header with results.  Show what you have tried. To get you started: You will need to grab entire table then loop row by row. Each time you find a row with a td that has that class you are in a new block of results and should store separately. An easy way is create a dict where the keys are the urls and the values are the county. You can then create add the right county to your results based on the current url.

Comment: I will try to figure this one out. It's not a rush so I want to learn on it. Will write back. Thank you!!